# Take arabian text between arabian numbers

Tags: c#, regex, unicode

I'm noob in a regular expressions and need help. Here part of source text (given me as string):

> ١ - عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ
>   رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم يَقُولُ: «إِنَّمَا
>   الْأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ، وَإِنَّمَا لِكُلِّ امْرِئٍ مَا نَوَى،
>   فَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى دُنْيَا يُصِيبُهَا أَوْ إِلَى
>   امْرَأَةٍ يَنْكِحُهَا، فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى مَا هَاجَرَ إِلَيْهِ».
>   (البخاري: ١) ٢ - عَنْ عَائشَةَ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهَا: أَنَّ الْحَارِثَ
>   بْنَ هِشَامٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ سَأَلَ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ
>   عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم فَقَالَ: يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، كَيْفَ يَأْتِيكَ
>   الْوَحْيُ؟ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم:
>   «أَحْيَانًا يَأْتِينِي مِثلَ صَلْصَلَة الْجَرَسِ - وَهُوَ أَشَدُّهُ
>   عَلَيَّ - فَيَفْصِمُ عَنِّي وَقَدْ وَعَيْتُ عَنْهُ مَا قَالَ،
>   وَأَحْيَانًا يَتَمثَّلُ لِيَ الْمَلَكُ رَجُلًا فَيُكَلِّمُنِي فَأَعِي
>   مَا يَقُولُ». قَالَتْ عَائشَةُ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْها: وَلَقَدْ
>   رَأَيْتُهُ يَنْزِلُ عَلَيْهِ الْوَحْيُ فِي الْيَوْمِ الشَّدِيدِ
>   الْبَرْدِ، فَيَفْصِمُ عَنْهُ وَإِنَّ جَبِينَهُ لَيَتَفَصَّدُ عَرَقًا.
>   (البخاري: ٢)

What pattern should I write for taking only text between numbers (include start number)? Expected result:

> ١ - عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ
>   رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم يَقُولُ: «إِنَّمَا
>   الْأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ، وَإِنَّمَا لِكُلِّ امْرِئٍ مَا نَوَى،
>   فَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى دُنْيَا يُصِيبُهَا أَوْ إِلَى
>   امْرَأَةٍ يَنْكِحُهَا، فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى مَا هَاجَرَ إِلَيْهِ».
>   (البخاري: ١)

and

> ٢ - عَنْ عَائشَةَ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهَا: أَنَّ الْحَارِثَ بْنَ هِشَامٍ
>   رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ سَأَلَ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ
>   وَسَلَّم فَقَالَ: يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، كَيْفَ يَأْتِيكَ الْوَحْيُ؟
>   فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم: «أَحْيَانًا
>   يَأْتِينِي مِثلَ صَلْصَلَة الْجَرَسِ - وَهُوَ أَشَدُّهُ عَلَيَّ -
>   فَيَفْصِمُ عَنِّي وَقَدْ وَعَيْتُ عَنْهُ مَا قَالَ، وَأَحْيَانًا
>   يَتَمثَّلُ لِيَ الْمَلَكُ رَجُلًا فَيُكَلِّمُنِي فَأَعِي مَا يَقُولُ».
>   قَالَتْ عَائشَةُ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْها: وَلَقَدْ رَأَيْتُهُ يَنْزِلُ
>   عَلَيْهِ الْوَحْيُ فِي الْيَوْمِ الشَّدِيدِ الْبَرْدِ، فَيَفْصِمُ
>   عَنْهُ وَإِنَّ جَبِينَهُ لَيَتَفَصَّدُ عَرَقًا. (البخاري: ٢)

May be there alternatives such as `Split`?

Comment: Do you just need `Regex.Matches(s, @"\d.*?\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value).ToList()`? Or if you just need Arabic digits, `@"[۱-۹].*?[۱-۹]+"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need arabian digits and other stuff such ` - ۱` at the start of each block

Comment: `@"\d.*?(?=\d|$)"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew will try later

Comment: Ok, I am just not accustomed to Arabic script. If you could provide a simplified ASCII-based sample with expected result, I could help with more certainty.

Answer (score 2):

I've given an initial shot at the question. Definitely a challenging one, Here's a javascript based regex for fetching the words in between the Arabic numbers.

`/[(\[\u0660-\u0669](.*?)[\u0660-\u0669]/g`

There might be a few bugs here and there but I guess this brings you a little closer to the answer. I've added another test case with

> ١  هذه هي اللغة العربية  ١

and tested with the paragraph you've provided.

Here's a complete example:

```
const regex = /[(\[\u0660-\u0669](.*?)[\u0660-\u0669]/g;
const str = `١ - عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم يَقُولُ: «إِنَّمَا الْأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ، وَإِنَّمَا لِكُلِّ امْرِئٍ مَا نَوَى، فَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى دُنْيَا يُصِيبُهَا أَوْ إِلَى امْرَأَةٍ يَنْكِحُهَا، فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى مَا هَاجَرَ إِلَيْهِ». (البخاري: ١) 

٢ - عَنْ عَائشَةَ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهَا: أَنَّ الْحَارِثَ بْنَ هِشَامٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ سَأَلَ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم فَقَالَ: يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، كَيْفَ يَأْتِيكَ الْوَحْيُ؟ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم: «أَحْيَانًا يَأْتِينِي مِثلَ صَلْصَلَة الْجَرَسِ - وَهُوَ أَشَدُّهُ عَلَيَّ - فَيَفْصِمُ عَنِّي وَقَدْ وَعَيْتُ عَنْهُ مَا قَالَ، وَأَحْيَانًا يَتَمثَّلُ لِيَ الْمَلَكُ رَجُلًا فَيُكَلِّمُنِي فَأَعِي مَا يَقُولُ». قَالَتْ عَائشَةُ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْها: وَلَقَدْ رَأَيْتُهُ يَنْزِلُ عَلَيْهِ الْوَحْيُ فِي الْيَوْمِ الشَّدِيدِ الْبَرْدِ، فَيَفْصِمُ عَنْهُ وَإِنَّ جَبِينَهُ لَيَتَفَصَّدُ عَرَقًا. (البخاري: ٢)

١هذه هي اللغة العربية١  

١ - عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم يَقُولُ: «إِنَّمَا الْأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ، وَإِنَّمَا لِكُلِّ امْرِئٍ مَا نَوَى، فَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى دُنْيَا يُصِيبُهَا أَوْ إِلَى امْرَأَةٍ يَنْكِحُهَا، فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى مَا هَاجَرَ إِلَيْهِ». (البخاري: ١) ٢ - عَنْ عَائشَةَ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهَا: أَنَّ الْحَارِثَ بْنَ هِشَامٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ سَأَلَ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم فَقَالَ: يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، كَيْفَ يَأْتِيكَ الْوَحْيُ؟ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم: «أَحْيَانًا يَأْتِينِي مِثلَ صَلْصَلَة الْجَرَسِ - وَهُوَ أَشَدُّهُ عَلَيَّ - فَيَفْصِمُ عَنِّي وَقَدْ وَعَيْتُ عَنْهُ مَا قَالَ، وَأَحْيَانًا يَتَمثَّلُ لِيَ الْمَلَكُ رَجُلًا فَيُكَلِّمُنِي فَأَعِي مَا يَقُولُ». قَالَتْ عَائشَةُ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْها: وَلَقَدْ رَأَيْتُهُ يَنْزِلُ عَلَيْهِ الْوَحْيُ فِي الْيَوْمِ الشَّدِيدِ الْبَرْدِ، فَيَفْصِمُ عَنْهُ وَإِنَّ جَبِينَهُ لَيَتَفَصَّدُ عَرَقًا. (البخاري: ٢)`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

The result of the group matches are as follows:

```
Found match, group 0: ١ - عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم يَقُولُ: «إِنَّمَا الْأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ، وَإِنَّمَا لِكُلِّ امْرِئٍ مَا نَوَى، فَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى دُنْيَا يُصِيبُهَا أَوْ إِلَى امْرَأَةٍ يَنْكِحُهَا، فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى مَا هَاجَرَ إِلَيْهِ». (البخاري: ١
Found match, group 1:  - عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم يَقُولُ: «إِنَّمَا الْأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ، وَإِنَّمَا لِكُلِّ امْرِئٍ مَا نَوَى، فَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى دُنْيَا يُصِيبُهَا أَوْ إِلَى امْرَأَةٍ يَنْكِحُهَا، فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى مَا هَاجَرَ إِلَيْهِ». (البخاري: 
Found match, group 0: ٢ - عَنْ عَائشَةَ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهَا: أَنَّ الْحَارِثَ بْنَ هِشَامٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ سَأَلَ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم فَقَالَ: يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، كَيْفَ يَأْتِيكَ الْوَحْيُ؟ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم: «أَحْيَانًا يَأْتِينِي مِثلَ صَلْصَلَة الْجَرَسِ - وَهُوَ أَشَدُّهُ عَلَيَّ - فَيَفْصِمُ عَنِّي وَقَدْ وَعَيْتُ عَنْهُ مَا قَالَ، وَأَحْيَانًا يَتَمثَّلُ لِيَ الْمَلَكُ رَجُلًا فَيُكَلِّمُنِي فَأَعِي مَا يَقُولُ». قَالَتْ عَائشَةُ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْها: وَلَقَدْ رَأَيْتُهُ يَنْزِلُ عَلَيْهِ الْوَحْيُ فِي الْيَوْمِ الشَّدِيدِ الْبَرْدِ، فَيَفْصِمُ عَنْهُ وَإِنَّ جَبِينَهُ لَيَتَفَصَّدُ عَرَقًا. (البخاري: ٢
Found match, group 1:  - عَنْ عَائشَةَ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهَا: أَنَّ الْحَارِثَ بْنَ هِشَامٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ سَأَلَ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم فَقَالَ: يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، كَيْفَ يَأْتِيكَ الْوَحْيُ؟ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم: «أَحْيَانًا يَأْتِينِي مِثلَ صَلْصَلَة الْجَرَسِ - وَهُوَ أَشَدُّهُ عَلَيَّ - فَيَفْصِمُ عَنِّي وَقَدْ وَعَيْتُ عَنْهُ مَا قَالَ، وَأَحْيَانًا يَتَمثَّلُ لِيَ الْمَلَكُ رَجُلًا فَيُكَلِّمُنِي فَأَعِي مَا يَقُولُ». قَالَتْ عَائشَةُ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْها: وَلَقَدْ رَأَيْتُهُ يَنْزِلُ عَلَيْهِ الْوَحْيُ فِي الْيَوْمِ الشَّدِيدِ الْبَرْدِ، فَيَفْصِمُ عَنْهُ وَإِنَّ جَبِينَهُ لَيَتَفَصَّدُ عَرَقًا. (البخاري: 
Found match, group 0: ١هذه هي اللغة العربية١
Found match, group 1: هذه هي اللغة العربية
Found match, group 0: ١ - عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم يَقُولُ: «إِنَّمَا الْأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ، وَإِنَّمَا لِكُلِّ امْرِئٍ مَا نَوَى، فَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى دُنْيَا يُصِيبُهَا أَوْ إِلَى امْرَأَةٍ يَنْكِحُهَا، فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى مَا هَاجَرَ إِلَيْهِ». (البخاري: ١
Found match, group 1:  - عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم يَقُولُ: «إِنَّمَا الْأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ، وَإِنَّمَا لِكُلِّ امْرِئٍ مَا نَوَى، فَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى دُنْيَا يُصِيبُهَا أَوْ إِلَى امْرَأَةٍ يَنْكِحُهَا، فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى مَا هَاجَرَ إِلَيْهِ». (البخاري: 
Found match, group 0: ٢ - عَنْ عَائشَةَ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهَا: أَنَّ الْحَارِثَ بْنَ هِشَامٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ سَأَلَ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم فَقَالَ: يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، كَيْفَ يَأْتِيكَ الْوَحْيُ؟ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم: «أَحْيَانًا يَأْتِينِي مِثلَ صَلْصَلَة الْجَرَسِ - وَهُوَ أَشَدُّهُ عَلَيَّ - فَيَفْصِمُ عَنِّي وَقَدْ وَعَيْتُ عَنْهُ مَا قَالَ، وَأَحْيَانًا يَتَمثَّلُ لِيَ الْمَلَكُ رَجُلًا فَيُكَلِّمُنِي فَأَعِي مَا يَقُولُ». قَالَتْ عَائشَةُ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْها: وَلَقَدْ رَأَيْتُهُ يَنْزِلُ عَلَيْهِ الْوَحْيُ فِي الْيَوْمِ الشَّدِيدِ الْبَرْدِ، فَيَفْصِمُ عَنْهُ وَإِنَّ جَبِينَهُ لَيَتَفَصَّدُ عَرَقًا. (البخاري: ٢
Found match, group 1:  - عَنْ عَائشَةَ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهَا: أَنَّ الْحَارِثَ بْنَ هِشَامٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ سَأَلَ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم فَقَالَ: يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، كَيْفَ يَأْتِيكَ الْوَحْيُ؟ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم: «أَحْيَانًا يَأْتِينِي مِثلَ صَلْصَلَة الْجَرَسِ - وَهُوَ أَشَدُّهُ عَلَيَّ - فَيَفْصِمُ عَنِّي وَقَدْ وَعَيْتُ عَنْهُ مَا قَالَ، وَأَحْيَانًا يَتَمثَّلُ لِيَ الْمَلَكُ رَجُلًا فَيُكَلِّمُنِي فَأَعِي مَا يَقُولُ». قَالَتْ عَائشَةُ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْها: وَلَقَدْ رَأَيْتُهُ يَنْزِلُ عَلَيْهِ الْوَحْيُ فِي الْيَوْمِ الشَّدِيدِ الْبَرْدِ، فَيَفْصِمُ عَنْهُ وَإِنَّ جَبِينَهُ لَيَتَفَصَّدُ عَرَقًا. (البخاري:
```

You're probably interested in the results of `group 1` of the regex matches which are

```
Found match, group 1:  - عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم يَقُولُ: «إِنَّمَا الْأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ، وَإِنَّمَا لِكُلِّ امْرِئٍ مَا نَوَى، فَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى دُنْيَا يُصِيبُهَا أَوْ إِلَى امْرَأَةٍ يَنْكِحُهَا، فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى مَا هَاجَرَ إِلَيْهِ». (البخاري: 

Found match, group 1:  - عَنْ عَائشَةَ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهَا: أَنَّ الْحَارِثَ بْنَ هِشَامٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ سَأَلَ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم فَقَالَ: يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، كَيْفَ يَأْتِيكَ الْوَحْيُ؟ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم: «أَحْيَانًا يَأْتِينِي مِثلَ صَلْصَلَة الْجَرَسِ - وَهُوَ أَشَدُّهُ عَلَيَّ - فَيَفْصِمُ عَنِّي وَقَدْ وَعَيْتُ عَنْهُ مَا قَالَ، وَأَحْيَانًا يَتَمثَّلُ لِيَ الْمَلَكُ رَجُلًا فَيُكَلِّمُنِي فَأَعِي مَا يَقُولُ». قَالَتْ عَائشَةُ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْها: وَلَقَدْ رَأَيْتُهُ يَنْزِلُ عَلَيْهِ الْوَحْيُ فِي الْيَوْمِ الشَّدِيدِ الْبَرْدِ، فَيَفْصِمُ عَنْهُ وَإِنَّ جَبِينَهُ لَيَتَفَصَّدُ عَرَقًا. (البخاري: 

Found match, group 1: هذه هي اللغة العربية

Found match, group 1:  - عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم يَقُولُ: «إِنَّمَا الْأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ، وَإِنَّمَا لِكُلِّ امْرِئٍ مَا نَوَى، فَمَنْ كَانَتْ هِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى دُنْيَا يُصِيبُهَا أَوْ إِلَى امْرَأَةٍ يَنْكِحُهَا، فَهِجْرَتُهُ إِلَى مَا هَاجَرَ إِلَيْهِ». (البخاري: 

Found match, group 1:  - عَنْ عَائشَةَ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهَا: أَنَّ الْحَارِثَ بْنَ هِشَامٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ سَأَلَ رَسُولَ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم فَقَالَ: يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، كَيْفَ يَأْتِيكَ الْوَحْيُ؟ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم: «أَحْيَانًا يَأْتِينِي مِثلَ صَلْصَلَة الْجَرَسِ - وَهُوَ أَشَدُّهُ عَلَيَّ - فَيَفْصِمُ عَنِّي وَقَدْ وَعَيْتُ عَنْهُ مَا قَالَ، وَأَحْيَانًا يَتَمثَّلُ لِيَ الْمَلَكُ رَجُلًا فَيُكَلِّمُنِي فَأَعِي مَا يَقُولُ». قَالَتْ عَائشَةُ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْها: وَلَقَدْ رَأَيْتُهُ يَنْزِلُ عَلَيْهِ الْوَحْيُ فِي الْيَوْمِ الشَّدِيدِ الْبَرْدِ، فَيَفْصِمُ عَنْهُ وَإِنَّ جَبِينَهُ لَيَتَفَصَّدُ عَرَقًا. (البخاري:
```

It's been more than 5 years since I last studied Arabic and this is the closest I could get to. I hope it answers your question. Here's a [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/4vLdOo/3) link to the regex matches.

Edit: By the way, I think there's a bug in the way Regex101 highlights the matched content. I've filed an [issue here on Github](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/939)

Comment: @anatol If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).